# javafx label cant fill the free space

Tags: javafx, alignment

I would like to achieve this layout in HBox

```
|[Message      ]|[Ok]|[Cancel]|
```

But I cant force the label to fill the free space at left, and I get this

```
|      [Message]|[Ok]|[Cancel]|
```

The *HBox.hgrow=ALWAYS* doesnt help.

The code is something like that below:

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="lblMessage" ... HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <Button fx:id="btnOk" ... HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
        <Button fx:id="btncancel" ... HBox.hgrow="NEVER" />
    </children>
</HBox>
```

How can I get the label to fill the left space ?

Answer (score 2):

The default maximum width of a `Label` is its preferred width. Setting the max width to a suitably large value should solve your issue.

Comment: A better option, IMO, would be to wrap the `Label` in an appropriate container that handles the sizing for you.

Comment: @Zephyr ok, but how do I know the extra container can force the Label to expands well ? I think the Label behaves differently than e.g TextField because it does good job in this case, fills the free space.